# git add or untracked file cancel

Tags: git, github, git-add

I have some questions about `undo git add` and `git reset`.

Recently I made some mistakes. 
First, I added all directory's files. And I want to cancel added. Then, some of the directories are removed after I wrote a `git rm-` command. 
Second, Still, several `Untracked Files` are maintained. And I found solutions. And I did `git reset`. but, it's still maintained.

In colclusion, I could't recover some of the directories and so many `Untracked Files` are maintained to `Untracked Files` status.

How can I solve this problem? 

At least, I hope to cancel `Untracked Files`.

Untracked files status
[image: it's my Untracked files status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git clean` for that.

`-n` will show that will be deleted

```
git clean -n
```

now delete files:

```
git clean -f
```

To remove directories, run `git clean -f -d` or `git clean -fd`

To remove ignored files, run `git clean -f -X` or `git clean -fX`

To remove ignored and non-ignored files, run `git clean -f -x` or `git clean -fx`

Comment: Thanks orvi! and i read your answer. Then, i have another question to yours. if i command "git clean", real file or directory in my computer is removed or just removed in github command part?

Comment: And add some question. if i command "git clean", real file or directory in my computer is removed or just removed in github command part?

Comment: `git clean` Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control means it will clear your working directories from your local direcotires.

Comment: Actually, i already removed some directories in my local. Then, i could't recover. In this case, can you give me another way to cancel "git add" do not remove something?